# Retrieve text after last back slash using SSIS Derived Column transformation

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014, etl, derived-column

Using SQL Server 2014.

I have a field that contains a string that contains a full file path i.e.

```
\\Server\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\File21.csv
```

I only want what is after the last backslash i.e.

```
File21.csv
```

So in the world of SQL I would use:

```
Select RIGHT([FileName],charindex('\',reverse([FileName]),1)-1) as FileNameNew from mytable
```

However, how do I do this in a Derived Column in SSIS?  There is no CHARINDEX so you have to use FINDSTRING.  This is my expression:

```
RIGHT( [FileName] , FINDSTRING('\', REVERSE( [FileName] ) ,1)  -1)
```

But it is not working, it keeps saying the single quotation mark was not expected.  I've also tried double quotes to no avail.

Comment: I don't have an SSDT install handy to test this on, but the backslash in SSIS expressions usually needs to be escaped with, of course, a backslash. So you _might_ get somewhere using `FINDSTRING('\\'...`. Worth a try, anyway.

Comment: @EricBrandt it accepted that but then the package fails with: [Derived Column [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Derived Column" failed because error code 0xC0049067 occurred

Comment: New errors are progress! I'm out, though, lacking an editor to play with.

Comment: haha - think I'll just revert to a SQL update after the import task.  Was just trying to contain it all in the DFT

Comment: @EricBrandt simplest solution is to use `TOKEN()` and `TOKENCOUNT()`. Since they are developed to solve similar cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have your parameters backwards. `FINDSTRING()` wants the thing you're searching first, then the thing you're searching for. And you will need double quotes and an escaped backslash. This should work:

```
RIGHT( [FileName] , FINDSTRING(REVERSE( [FileName] ), "\\" ,1)  -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Even if this can be done using `RIGHT()` or `SUBSTRING()` functions. I prefer using `TOKEN` and `TOKENCOUNT()` function to do that:

```
TOKEN([File Name],"\\",TOKENCOUNT([File Name],"\\"))
```

*Example:*

```
TOKEN("\\\\Server\\Folder1\\Folder2\\Folder3\\File21.csv","\\",TOKENCOUNT("\\\\Server\\Folder1\\Folder2\\Folder3\\File21.csv","\\"))
```

*Result:*

> File21.csv